# How to tell if someone has left

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I was wondering how I could check if someone has left the site/page and perform an action after they left. I was reading on here and I found this:

> No, there isn't. The best you can do is send an AJAX request every X seconds (perhaps only if the user moves the mouse). If the server doesn't receive any requests for 2X seconds, assume that the user left.

That's what I had planned for before but how could you make the server do something (in my case it's to remove them from the DB) if they stop sending the request? An example I can think of is how on Facebook when you go to the site you tell them you're here and online which marks you as online in chat but when you leave it marks you as offline. How is that possible?

Edit: After a while of using cron jobs I found out that web hosting sites don't like running cron jobs often enough to generate a "live" feelings on your site. So instead I found node.js and it works a 1000x better and is much simpler. I'd recommend anyone with the same issue to use it, it's very cheap to buy hosting for and it's simple to learn, if you know Javascript you can build in it no problem. Just be sure to know how Async works.

Comment: What do you want the server to do? It can't interact with the user anymore.

Comment: Don't rely on Javascript, users can disable it.

Comment: @TheZ In this day and age, I think it's safe to assume close to 99% of users have JS on. Many sites (StackOverflow included) are hard to use with JS disabled.

Comment: cron job to check inactive for X minutes

Comment: @Oded Yes I know that's is why I'm asking. That person said it was possible so I wanted to know how that would work.

Comment: Any user with JS disabled in 2012 is a user I wouldn't plan to cater for on my website.

Comment: IIRC Facebook used an image that just kept on loading to determine if the user was still connected. As soon as that connection was broken, FB assumed you disconnected. I don't know if that's still the case.

Comment: @Dagon That's perfect! If you want to leave an answer I'll give you some rep.

Comment: @NullUserException so FB assume use disconnected when user reload page

Comment: @Tarun I imagine it had a timeout window, so if the connection is reestablished within X seconds you would still be "on."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A not uncommon approach is to run a cron job periodically that checks the list of users, and does XYZ if they have been inactive for X minutes.

Comment: Only problem I can foresee with this approach unless its some synchronous approach which even then has bad side effects if not handled right, is that if you have a high enough user base and a single machine, this is going to become very taxing very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses the XMPP protocol via the Jabber service to have a *constant* or *real-time* connection with the user. However, implementing one isn't an easy task at all. The most simple solution would be, as mentioned in the comments, to have the client make AJAX requests to the server every several seconds, so that the server may check whether the user is still viewing the site or not.

You might want to check out [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251150/expiring-custom-php-session-when-browser-closes), which might be related to yours.

Comment: I get that the user would make ajax calls over and over, but how can the server check if you stopped making those calls?

Comment: @RosengustaGarrett: each user would need to have an unique ID, and their *state*, or online availability, would be stored on a database; the server would then check the time of the last AJAX call of a given user, and determine whether or not the client has closed the connection.

Answer (score 1):

The only method I ever remember in my time developing is one that's not 100% reliable as a number of factors can actually and most likely cause it to either misfired, or not even run fully. Up to and including someone disabling JavaScript. Which grant it isn't highly likely with the way websites of today are put together. But people have the option to turn it off, and then people who are acting maliciously tend to have it off as well.

Anyway, the method I have read about but never put much stock in is, the `onunload()` event. That you tie into something like the `<body>` tag.

Example:

```
<body onunload="myFunction()">
```

Where `myFunction()` is a bit of JavaScript to do whatever it is your seeking to have done.

Again not superbly reliable for many reasons, but I think in all it's the best you have with almost all client side languages.